# Getting storage array data from contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, testing

I have a solidity contract which stores an array of `Proposal` information:

```
contract Submissions {

    Proposal[] public proposals;

    struct Proposal {
        // ....
    }
}
```

In a test (using truffle framework), I am trying to access the proposal data:

`const proposals = await Submissions.proposals();`

But I get this exception:

> Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

I don't understand this as it is not a function and therefore requires no arguments. Elsewhere in my tests I have successfully gathered contract data using this method (although not for arrays) - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [automatically generated getter](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) for an array accepts a single parameter: the index into the array.

So you should be able to call `proposals(0)`, `proposals(1)`, etc. to fetch members of the array.

Comment: Just one question though, indexing like that seems to return an address rather than the entire struct that I have defined - why is that? And what address is it referring to?

Comment: You might have to share what you're seeing. Each call should return a `Proposal`, though I think some members of the struct might be skipped if their types are  not supported by the ABI encoder. Without knowing what's in `Proposal`, it's hard to speculate further.